# After finding the column space basis, do you simplify them?

Tags: linear-algebra

So the subspace $U=\operatorname{span}\left\{(1,5,-6)^T, (2,6,-8)^T, (3,7,-10)^T, (4,8,12)^T \right\}$. To find the basis, I row reduced the matrix and found that the basis of column space is $\left\{(1,5,-6)^T, (2,6,-8)^T,(4,8,12)^T \right\}$ and dimension is $3$. However, the answer says the basis is $\left\{(1,5,-6)^T, (0,1,-1)^T, (0,0,1)^T \right\}$ as I don't get where the later two columns come from. Can someone suggest why?

Comment: $(0,1-1) = \frac{1}{2}(1,5,-6)-\frac{1}{4}(2,6,-8)$ and $(0,0,1) =  \frac{1}{12}(1,5,-6)-\frac{1}{8}(2,6,-8)+\frac{1}{24}(4,8,12)$ so your basis set is equivalent to theirs.  Theirs is just a little easier to work with as it contains more zeros and ones.  An even simpler basis set is $\left\{(1,0,0)^T,(0,1,0)^T,(0,0,1)^T\right\}$.  Confirm for yourself that this one is also equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

When you put the trasposed matrix in *row-echelon form*, you get
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-6\\2&6&-8\\3&7&-10\\4&8&12\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-6\\0&-4&4\\0&-8&8\\0&-12&36\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-6\\0&-4&4\\0&0&0\\0&0&24\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-6\\0&1&-1\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Now at each step, rows generate the same span as the original rows. As the final non-zero rows are linearly independent, they make up a basis of the span.